# ¿Se puede utilizar una aplicación con BD en una maquina cliente sin SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Buen día,

Tengo la siguiente cuestión, trabaje en una aplicación de escritorio dentro de C# usando Windows Forms, ya estas terminada y funciona correctamente.

Esta aplicación trabaja como un checador de entrada y salida del personal de la empresa, trabaja conectado a una BD de SQL server.

Esta aplicación sera instalada dentro de una tiendas de la empresa la cuales no cuentan con SQL Server, mi cuestion es:

¿Se puede poner una base de datos portable para almacenar la información o alguna otra forma como pueda almacenar la información o solamente instalando SQL en las maquina?

Saludos, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sql server (si no es la version express) requiere un servidor sql server.

Comment: Puedes utilizar la versión SQL Server Compact, que es una BD ligera en comparación a las versiones avanzadas de SQL Server. Lo puedes descargar de la página oficial de Microsoft o haciendo una búsqueda en internet

Comment: SQL Server Compact, SQLite...hay varias opciones disponibles

Comment: yo uso SQLite es buena opción

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos creo que usare ya sea SQLite o SQL Server Compact

Comment: Si el problema es que no quieres instalar SQL en las tiendas, la otra alternativa es configurar el servidor de la empresa (entiéndase como la sede principal) con un VPN para acceder a la base de datos y con cambios pequeños en la cadena de conexión de la aplicación, podrás conectarla sin problema.